# How to archive the whole website?

Tags: archive.org

To save a single page via *Wayback Machine* I can go to:

- http://web.archive.org/save/https://somewebsite.example.com/

How can I archive the website recursively by *Wayback Machine*?

---

There is some project such as [`wayback-machine-downloader`](https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader), but I'm looking for a feature which allows me the upload the website recursively.

Comment: Are you having any difficulty using the URL technique you mention in your question?  I've had it work hundreds of times, but I've also had it fail many times too.  I get about an 80% success rate, even for the same pages on different dates.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Copy and pasting each URL one-by-one manually into a web form is fairly impractical and human error prone for savings hundreds or thousands of pages or more.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since *Wayback Machine* doesn't provide such feature, I've found some workaround.

1. First, mirror the website using `wget`, e.g.

   ```
   wget -m https://example.com/
   ```
2. Then use `curl` to archive all pages one by one that you've downloaded.

   ```
   find . -name "*.html" -exec curl -v "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}" ';'
   ```

   <sup>Note: You can change `.html` to `.php`, or include certain type of files.</sup>

Comment: If the site doesn't use extensions (such as html or php - like SE is setup), how do you do adapt your command?

Comment: You can change `-name "*.html"` to `-type f` to include all files.

Comment: How does this work with query parameters?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore: it prints 429 Too Many Requests

Comment: @simplegamer I am on Window 7, so how could I implement this solutiob?

Comment: The `--convert-links` arguments can be useful as well - the former makes the links relative; this does require adding the domain URL into the "save/https:///domain" but will help when the site doesn't use absolute URLs.

Comment: What happens when one of the saves fails because of some issue on the Wayback Machine's end?

Comment: @simplegamer: If doing this with many files, append `-exec sleep 1 ';'` to the end of the command in this answer to wait 1 second between requests. Raise or lower the number as appropriate until you no longer get the 429 rate errors. (Better yet, use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, for example: `find . -name "*.html" -execdir curl -v "https://web.archive.org/save/https://{}" ';' -execdir sleep 1 ';' `)

Answer (score 13):

If you wish to archive a small website, the [Archive Team](https://www.archiveteam.org/) maintains the [ArchiveBot](https://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=ArchiveBot), an IRC bot where you can request to crawl websites. The Archive Team will then submit the crawled pages to the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine.

Comment: This worked for me, just [join them on IRC](https://wiki.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=ArchiveBot#Details) and ask.

Comment: seems to require "voice"? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awp77.png

Answer (score 6):

Using the Wayback Machine's [Save Page Now](https://web.archive.org/save) interface, you can now also save outlinks (linked pages).

A quote from the original 2019 [announcement](https://blog.archive.org/2019/10/23/the-wayback-machines-save-page-now-is-new-and-improved/):

> You can now save all the “outlinks” of a web page with a single click. By selecting the “save outlinks” checkbox you can save the requested page and also all linked pages

The Wayback Machine's [Save Page Now](https://web.archive.org/save) interface can be used without an account however extra features like **saving outlinks**, **saving screenshots**, and saving pages to your  **my web archive** all require signing in.

Comment: From where is this option available?

Comment: I've edited the answer (hope they'll accept) that [Save Page Now](https://web.archive.org/save) requires a **Sign In** in order to use this option (which was added back in late 2019). @kenorb please consider changing the accepted answer into this one!

Answer (score 4):

The Wayback Machine doesn't offer a way to submit an entire site, only a single page as you've already found. This is touched on in a couple of points of [their Wayback Machine FAQ](http://archive.org/about/faqs.php#The_Wayback_Machine):

> **Can I add pages to the Wayback Machine?**
>
> On https://archive.org/web you can use the "Save Page Now" feature to save a specific page one time. **This does not currently add the URL to any future crawls nor does it save more than that one page. It does not save multiple pages, directories or entire sites**.

and

> **How can I get my site included in the Wayback Machine?**
>
> Much of our archived web data comes from our own crawls or from Alexa Internet's crawls. **Neither organization has a "crawl my site now!" submission process**. Internet Archive's crawls tend to find sites that are well linked from other sites. The best way to ensure that we find your web site is to make sure it is included in online directories and that similar/related sites link to you.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Just because there is no official way to do it, the task is not impossible to perform. In fact, it should be pretty easy to whip up a script that adds links recursively.

Comment: @d-b, [kenorb's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115426/145660) appears to be what you were asking for. Incidentally, this answer is more useful to me in the moment, as I just wanted The WaybackMachine to capture one page for me now.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360001513491-Save-Pages-in-the-Wayback-Machine) on archive.org also suggests a paid service which will do the crawling for you as often as you'd like:

> 5. Sign up for an Archive-It Account
>
> [Archive-It](https://archive-it.org/) is a subscription service provided by Internet Archive that allows you to run your own crawling projects without any technical expertise.  Tell us what to crawl and how often to crawl it, and we execute the crawl and put the results in the Wayback Machine.

This is probably not what you're after, but for some businesses this service might be useful. I assume it helps to fund archive.org, which otherwise is free.

Comment: I can *login* to archive-it, but I can not sign up to archive-it, suggesting this service is no longer available.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it's only open to partners? They advertise the services [here](https://support.archive-it.org/hc/en-us/articles/209671666-Introduction-to-Archive-It-Research-Services-ARS-).

Try to [contact the support](https://archive-it.org/contact-us) perhaps?

I'm not a partner/user of that service so only shared the info I found online.

Comment: Possible. I put in a request on the ArchiveBot (mentioned in this answer, above, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129886/29284), and that seems to have done the trick, too.

Comment: There is no self-registration availability.  It seems they must create the accounts internally after you fill out the [contact form](https://archive-it.org/contact-us) and subscribe to a paid plan.