# Archive the whole website on the Wayback Machine

Tags: archive.org

I want to archive a website and all of its content on the Wayback Machine. I have looked at this question, [How to archive the whole website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115369/how-to-archive-the-whole-website), but when I tried the solution listed there it would only archive the images and files but not the actual webpages.

Comment: answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126460/186471

Answer (score -2):

The project archive.org automatically saves the websites after certain periods of time. If your website is unnoticed by them you can try emailing them. If you want to archive your website just for yourself then you could use some softwares (I recommend [HTTrack](https://httrack.com)) to do that task.