# How to add an entire forum to the Wayback Machine Internet Archive?

Tags: archive.org

There's a forum that I like to read because it has a lot of useful technical information on it.  But the site is owned by one person and I'm worried he might retire.  I checked [archive.org](http://archive.org) and it appears that the forum is only partially included.  Is there a way that I can get the entire forum archived without the site owner's assistance (I doubt he'd object but he doesn't seem interested in the effort).

Comment: you can add it all by yourself

Answer (score 1):

> Many people have shown interest in making sure the Wayback Machine has
> copies of the web pages they care about most. These saved pages can be
> cited, shared, linked to – and they will continue to exist even after
> the original page changes or is removed from the web.
>
> There are several ways to save pages and whole sites so that they
> appear in the Wayback Machine.  Here are 5 of them.
>
> ### 1. Save Page Now
>
> Put a URL into **[the form](https://archive.org/web/)**, press the button, and we save the page.  You
> will instantly have a permanent URL for your page. Please note, this
> method only saves a single page, not the whole site.
>
> [image: 0]
>
> At the moment, there are a few exceptions for this method – some sites
> prohibit crawling, a few have SSL (security) settings that make it
> break – but this method will work for most pages.  The feature saves
> the page you enter including the images and CSS.  It does not save any
> of the outlinks, and can’t be used to initiate a crawl of an entire
> web site. We do not keep your IP address, so your submission is
> anonymous.
>
> ---
>
> ### **2. Browser extensions and add-ons**
>
> Install the **[Wayback Machine Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wayback-machine/fpnmgdkabkmnadcjpehmlllkndpkmiak)** in your browser.  Go to a
> page you want to archive, click the icon in your toolbar, and select
> Save Page Now. We will save the page and give you a permanent URL.
>
> [image: 0]
>
> The same provisos from "Save Page Now" apply – there are some pages
> where it won’t work, and it only saves one page at a time.  One plus
> to installing the extension though is that now as you surf around,
> when you run into a missing page we will alert you if we have a saved
> copy.
>
> More extensions, apps, and add-ons:
>
> - **[Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wayback-machine_new/)**
> - **[Safari Extension](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=archive.org.waybackmachine-ZSFX78H3ZT)**
> - **[iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wayback-machine/id1201888313)**
> - **[Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.archive.waybackmachine)**
>
> ---
>
> ### **3. Wikipedia JavaScript Bookmarklet**
>
> Nobody loves a primary source more than a Wikipedia editor.  To that
> end, they offer a **[Wayback Machine JavaScript Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Using_the_Wayback_Machine#JavaScript_bookmarklet)** that allows
> you to quickly save a web page from any browser.
>
> [image: 0]
>
> ---
>
> ### **4. Volunteer for Archive Team**
>
> Archive Team is an entirely volunteer-driven group who are interested
> in saving Internet history.  Many of the sites and pages they save end
> up in the Wayback Machine.  Visit the **[Archive Team site](http://www.archiveteam.org/)** to learn more
> about how to volunteer with them.
>
> ---
>
> ### **5. Sign up for an Archive-It Account**
>
> **[Archive-It](https://archive-it.org/)** is a subscription service provided by Internet Archive that
> allows you to run your own crawling projects without any technical
> expertise.  Tell us what to crawl and how often to crawl it, and we
> execute the crawl and put the results in the Wayback Machine.
>
> Archive-It is a paid subscription service with technical and web
> archivist support. This option is most appropriate for organizations
> that have a mandate to save certain types or categories of web content
> on a regular basis. If your institution is a current Archive-It
> partner, contact them for how you can contribute.
>
> ---
>
> **[https://help.archive.org/Save-Pages-in-the-Wayback-Machine](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360001513491-Save-Pages-in-the-Wayback-Machine)**

Comment: Thank you.  I read that page too.  But it doesn't answer my question - how to archive an entire forum rather than just a single page.  Forums often have hundreds or thousands of topics so it is not practical to archive all of them one by one.  I took a look at Archive-It too but it appears to be an institutional product, not for individual use.

Comment: well, these are the only options. yes, Archive-It is a paid product which could, however, do the whole job in a few clicks. Apart from that, your only option is to do page-by-page by yourself or contact archive.org support and convince them to scrape it all on their expenses in "benefit of future mankind"

Comment: @WebUserLearner https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers