# Archive all the urls of a website to WaybackMachine (https://web.archive.org/)

Tags: archive.org

The Oxford English Dictionary website offers the entries of the dictionary online, just by counting numbers in the final numerical expression in its URL: *https://www.oed.com/oed2/00000001*, *https://www.oed.com/oed2/00000002* ... the last url being *https://www.oed.com/oed2/00291601*

Surprisingly enough, https://web.archive.org has not yet archive them all, and I'd love to know how I can do/request so .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to archive the whole website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115369/how-to-archive-the-whole-website)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time, you can save the pages (one by one) yourself. This [page](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360001513491-Save-Pages-in-the-Wayback-Machine) describes how to do it.

> 1. Save Page Now
>
> Put a URL into the form, press the button, and we save the page.  You will instantly have a permanent URL for your page. Please note, this method only saves a single page, not the whole site.

OR

> 2. Browser extensions and add-ons
>
> Install the Wayback Machine Chrome extension in your browser.  Go to a page you want to archive, click the icon in your toolbar, and select Save Page Now. We will save the page and give you a permanent URL.

OR if you want more pages, do as indicated [here](https://blog.archive.org/2019/10/23/the-wayback-machines-save-page-now-is-new-and-improved/):

> You can now save all the “outlinks” of a web page with a single click. By selecting the “save outlinks” checkbox you can save the requested page (and all the embedded resources that make up that page) and also all linked pages (and all the embedded resources that make up those pages). Often, a request to archive a single web page, with outlinks, will cause us to archive hundreds of URLs.  Every one of which is shown via the SPN interface as it is archived.

Edit: I have found this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115369/how-to-archive-the-whole-website) on Web Applications which provides some answers. Which also might render my answer a bit pointless since another user there provide it already. If there are mods reading this, should I delete this answer?

Comment: There're 291601 entries (the last url is https://www.oed.com/oed2/00291601)

Comment: @user580054 See edit

Comment: Thnx. I am on Window 7, so how could I implement the solution in this answer? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115369/how-to-archive-the-whole-website

Comment: @GJC I think there should not be a problem even with Windows 7 as the saving is not done directly on your PC. You just need to go to archive.org, enter the URL of the page to archive, their servers will do the work.